# Swift3、スワイプでページをめくる際に、両開きできるようにしたい。

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift3で、Swipe Gesture Recognizerを使ってスワイプすると、右左どちらに向かってスワイプしても、右開き（右から左への画面遷移）しかできません。左から画面遷移できる方法がありましたら教えて頂きたいのですが、よろしくお願い致します。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //左にスワイプ
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    //右にスワイプ
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
    rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
}


   func swipeAction(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    switch swipe.direction {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "backView", sender: self)
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goView", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pageViewControllerを使うと、GestureやAnimationを何も実装しなくても実現できます（質問の意図に添えているか自信がないですが）

Answer (score 0):

`Swipe Gesture Recognizer`と画面遷移アニメーションには関係性はなにもありません。
（`Swipe Gesture Recognizer`を使ったからといって自然と遷移アニメーションが変わったりはしません）

オリジナルの画面遷移アニメーションは、`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`や`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`を使うことで自分で実装することができます。